# Ramified Field Extensions

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

Let $k$ be a field of $char(k)=0$ und we consider an field exension $L/k$  with $[L:k]=n$.

Set $M:= L((t^{1/n}))$ and $F:= k((t))$.

I'm looking for a proof of following two statements:

1) If the residual field $k_F := \mathcal{O}_F/\pi_F $ equals $k$, then $M/F$ is totally ramified.

2) $char(k) =0$, therefore, $M/F$ is tamely ramified.

I'm not an expert on the field of algebraic number theory/ local field theory so unfortunately I have rather no idea how to show it. I was just curious about the both statements.

Nevertheless for 1) I tried follwing: $M/F$ is totally ramified iff $k_M= \mathcal{O}_M/\pi_M = \mathcal{O}_F/\pi_F= k_F$. We know $k_F=k$. Why $k_M=k$?

I know that if $p$ is the unique prime of $F$ then it ramifies via $p\mathcal{O}_M= q_1 q_2 ... q_d$ into primes in $\mathcal{O}_M$ but from here I'm stuck.

Could anybody give proofs for the two statements. 
The main goal is to show that $M/F$ is cyclic extension and I think that one can show this also directly but from didactical point of view (in order to learn some proof techniques from ANT) I would to prefer to go the way through steps 1) and 2).

Comment: If $k$ is algebraically closed, then $L$ cannot have degree $n$ over $k$, unless $n=1$. Do you mean $k$ any field of characteristic $0$? Also the residue field is not $F/O_F$, it's defined to be (in this case) $k[[t]]$ (a local ring) mod its maximal ideal, which is then just $k$ (you may write this $O_F/m_F$ where $m_F$ is the maximal ideal of $O_F$).

Comment: Yes, indeed that make no sense. I guess that then $k_F=k$ is an extra assumption.

Comment: And I don't there needs a proof, that the residue fields are the same is the definition of totally ramified extension of local fields (what needs is a proof is that it is related to the ramification in the field they are the completion of). For tamely ramified it means it becomes a Galois extension after an unramified extension.

Comment: @reuns:Possibly I missunderstand you but is this what is to proof, insn't it?
As you pointed out, a totally ramified extension of lfs is characterized
by property that the residue fields for both fields coinside.
We know that $k_F=k$. But is it obvoiusly that also $k_M=k$?

Which completion wrt  which valuation do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the maybe stupid question but now I have a huge lack of knowledge on this topic

Comment: The residue field of $k((t))$ is $k[[t]]/(t) \cong k$. It is not obvious but there is only one local ring $R$ such that $k((t)) = Frac(R)$ (because the square root is $k((t)) \to k((t))$ for the elements of the form $t^{-2n} (a+t b(t)), a \in (k^*)^2, b \in k[[t]]\}$ but not on a larger set)

Comment: @reuns: Yes, $k[[t]]/(t) \cong k$ is obviously. What about $\mathcal{O}/\pi_M$ for $M:= L((t^{1/n}))$? where $\pi_M$ is the unique maximal ideal of the integers. To show 1) we need $\mathcal{O}/\pi_M =k$, right?

Comment: With $u = t^{1/n}$ not algebraic over $ k' = L$ then $L((t^{1/n}))= k'((u))$ whose residue field is $k'[[u]]/(u) \cong k'$.

Comment: @reuns: But then we get $k_F = k \neq L = k_M$. So under this conditions 1) can't be true?

Comment: You probably meant to look at the tower of extensions $k(\zeta_n)((t^{1/n}))/k((t^{1/n}))/k((t))$ and $k(\zeta_n)((t^{1/n}))/k(\zeta_n)((t))/k((t))$ and try to generalize ($\zeta_n^n = 1$)

Comment: @reuns: I'm not sure what you intend to deduce by comparing these towers. Calculate the index? In the previous posts we could show that $M$ and $F$ have different residue field so according to the definition the extension $M/F$ can't be totally ramified. So 1) is wrong? Please, correct me if my reasonings are nonsense.